# topology induced on Y by f?

Tags: general-topology

I don't think I understand the definition of induced topology very well, since I got confused trying to prove it's a topology.

I have this definition:

$f:Y \to X$, $\mathcal{T^x}$ topology on $X$

The induced topology on Y is the $\mathcal{T^y} = \{f^{-1}(U):U\in \mathcal{T^x}\}$

I do understand why $\emptyset$ and $Y$ are in $\mathcal{T^y}$, but I am having trouble with the other parts.

For example, I need to show $\cup f^{-1}(U_{\alpha})$ is open. We have that $\cup f^{-1}(U_{\alpha}) = f^{-1}(\cup U_{\alpha})$ and $\cup U_{\alpha}$ is open, but why does the $f^{-1}(U_{\alpha})$ have to be open. It doesn't say f is continuous. Am I missing somethng in the definition. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: $\cup f^{-1}(U_\alpha)\in \mathcal{T}^y$ since it is preimage of an element (ie $\cup U_\alpha\in \mathcal{T}^x$) from $\mathcal{T}^x$.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sigur. This made it so clear! :)

Comment: $f$ actually *is* continuous. This topology is defined so that it contains just enough open sets to make $f$ continuous. It is the coarsest topology on $Y$ under which $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @MPW I understand now that it's continuous, but I wasn't sure if I could use that in the proof, since the definition doesn't say anything about continuity

Comment: You can't use that, because you would be assuming what you are trying to prove.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks @MPW

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $O_i \in \mathcal{T}^y$, for $i \in I$. This means by definition of $\mathcal{T}^y$ that there are $U_i \in \mathcal{T}^x$ such that $O_i = f^{-1}[U_i]$ for all $i$. Now, $\cup_i O_i = \cup_i f^{-1}[U_i] = f^{-1}[\cup_i U_i]$, as $f^{-1}$ and unions commute. But $U = \cup_i U_i$ is in $\mathcal{T}^x$, because all $U_i$ are and a topology is closed under all unions. So we have written $\cup_i O_i$ as the inverse image of a member of $\mathcal{T}^x$, so by definition it is in $\mathcal{T}^y$, as required. The proof for finite intersections is quite similar.

$f$ is clearly continuous: take any $U$ open in $X$, i.e. $U \in \mathcal{T}^x$. Then *by definition* $f^{-1}[U] \in \mathcal{T}^y$, i.e. $f^{-1}[U]$ is open in $Y$.

Note that in order for $f$ to be continuous at all we need *at least* all sets of the form $f^{-1}[U]$, where $U \in \mathcal{T}^x$. And as it turns out (so first part of the proof), these sets already form a topology, so it is the minimal topology that makes $f$ continuous.

Answer (score 0):

So this is the induced topology because it is defining all the sets we need to be open to make $f$ continuous open. A simple way to describe the topology on $Y$ is if a subset is the preimage of an open set in $X$ then it is open.

Answer (score 0):

A subset $W$ of $Y$ is open if $W$ has the form $f^{-1}(U)$ where $U$ is an open set of $X$. Since $W=\cup f^{-1}(U)=f^{-1}(V)$ where $V=\cup U$ is an open set of $X$ we can say that $W$ is an open of $Y$.

This not need $f$ is continuous but we can say that the topology induced makes on $f$ a continuous function from $(Y,\mathcal T^y)$ to $(X,\mathcal T^x)$. One might even say that $\mathcal T^y$  is the smallest topology making on $f$ a continuous map from $(Y,\mathcal T^y)$ to $(X,\mathcal T^x)$.